# Split audio track into segments by BPM and analyse each segment using Superpowered iOS

Tags: ios, audio, superpowered

I have been using the Superpowered iOS library to analyse audio and extract BPM, loudness, pitch data. I'm working on an iOS Swift 3.0 project and have been able to get the C classes work with Swift using the Bridging headers for ObjC.

The problem I am running into is that whilst I can create a decoder object, extract audio from the Music Library and store it as a .WAV - I am unable to create a decoder object for just snippets of the extracted audio and get the analyser class to return data.

My approach has been to create a decoder object as follows:

```
var decodeAttempt = decoder!.open(self.originalFilePath, metaOnly: false, offset: offsetBytes, length: lengthBytes, stemsIndex: 0)
```

'offsetBytes' and 'LengthBytes' I think are the position within the audio file. As I have already decompressed audio, stored it as WAV and then am providing it to the decoder here, I am calculating the offset and length using the PCM Wave audio formula of 44100 x 2 x 16 / 8 = 176400 bytes per second. Then using this to specify a start point and length in bytes. I'm not sure that this is the correct way to do this as the decoder will return 'Unknown file format'.

Any ideas or even alternative suggestions of how to achieve the title of this question? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset and length parameters of the SuperpoweredDecoder are there because of the Android APK file format, where bundled audio files are simply concatenated to the package.

Despite a WAV file is as "uncompressed" as it can be, there is a header at the beginning, so offset and length are not a good way for this purpose. Especially as the header is present at the beginning only, and without the header decoding is not possible.

You mention that you can extract audio to PCM (and save to WAV). Then you have the answer in your hand: just submit different extracted portions to different instances of the SuperpoweredOfflineAnalyzer.

Comment: Thanks Gabor - I had the same thought initially but was sidetracked when I saw the 'offset,length' parameters and assumed it was to do with the WAV file - I'll try your suggestion!